# jquery how to collect all link value from a object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i have a object, just i need to collect and store the object which contains the lable as link in to a new array.. can any one give me the best way to do this?

myobeject:

```
            var xploreMaps = {
            radious:55,
            stroke:5,strokeColor:'#fff',
            opacity:0.8,fontSize:13,line:10,
            cRtext:{
                length:4,
                lineColor:'#7d2c2c',
                prop:{
                    0:{link:'motionGraphics.html',color:'#595959',text:'Motion Graphics'},
                    1:{link:'video.html',color:'#306465',text:'Video'},
                    2:{link:'photography.html',color:'#7e6931',text:'Photography'},
                    3:{link:'copyRight.html',color:'#4c4966',text:'Copywriting'}
                    }
            },
            cBtext:{
                length:3,
                lineColor:'#4c839d',
                prop:{
                    0:{link:'imagination.html',color:'#595959',text:'Imagination'},
                    1:{link:'innovation.html',color:'#306465',text:'Innovation'},
                    2:{link:'ideation.html',color:'#7e6931',text:'Ideation'}
                    }
            },
            cGtext:{
                length:5,
                lineColor:'#579549',
                prop:{
                    0:{link:'catalogs .html',color:'#7a5967',text:'Catalogs',
                    subLink:{0:{link:'SEO_SMM.html',color:'#4e4b69',text:'SEO/SMM',align:'top'},1:{link:'site_analytics.html',color:'#545454',text:'Site analytics',align:'btm'}}},
                    1:{link:'socialmedia.html',color:'#1e9ead',text:'Innovation'},
                    2:{link:'loyalty .html',color:'#8fad34',text:'Ideation'},
                    3:{link:'promotions .html',color:'#563b64',text:'Promotions'},
                    4:{link:'implementations.html',color:'#2c6566',text:'Implementations',
                    subLink:{0:{link:'integrating.html',color:'#4c4a66',text:'Integrating',align:'top'},1:{link:'payment.html',color:'#948048',text:'Payment',align:'btm'}}}
                    }
            }
}
```

My function which i try:

```
var links = []//just i need all the objects which contains the link.

        var objFinder = function (obj){
            $.each(obj,function(key,val){
                if(key == 'link' && typeof val == 'string'){
                    links.push(val)
                }else{
                    objFinder(val);//throws errors;
                }
            })
        }
        objFinder(xploreMaps);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that your objects have a property `length`. That is messing up the processing. See the fiddle I created here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Zfdj/

I just commented out the `length` property and it seems to work properly. I also did some minor cleanup such as adding missing semi-colons but that wasn't the main issue.

You can see the jQuery bug (invalid) here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7260